# th convert.lua segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: python, lua, neural-network, segmentation-fault, nlp

I am trying to run a preprocessing part of a project of

## Neural Question Generation

I am using Linux OS, and using the command line to run the commands appear in the GitHub project:

"https://github.com/xinyadu/nqg".

When I am writing the commend: "**th convert.lua**"

there is a line:

"**array = npy4th.loadnpy("qg.src.840B.300d.npy")**"
after running this line, I get an error: "**segmentation fault (core dumped)**".

I don't understand what I do wrong and what the error in this context means.

It is my final project and hope you can help me!!

Comment: I don't know Lua but I would look at the problem if I managed to replicate your environment. It's not clear to me how to install the things that are needed so that I can run the 'th' command.

Comment: The 'th' command is connecting to torch. 
https://dwijaybane.wordpress.com/2017/07/22/installing-torch-7-deep-learning-on-ubuntu-16-04/

Comment: I got stuck again, so I will leave you to it. Good luck.